# How to filter items in Vue 3？

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-filter

In Vue 2, we filter items conveniently just using `|` and `filters`. But it isn't in Vue 3.

As we know，we can just use "computed" to change a value to another.

But how can I change values of an array?

*Vue 2*

```html
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="(index,value) in array1" :key="index">
   {{ value | valuefilter}}
  </li>
</ul>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
...
export {
...
  filters:{
    valuefilter(value){
      return '$'+ value
    }
  }
...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a computed to filter the data beforehand to the way you want it, then iterate over that computed instead of the raw data.

This is essentially what a filter would do, plus the advantage of keeping the template a little cleaner:

*Template*

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="(value, index) in filtered" :key="index">
   {{ value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

*Options API*

```js
data: () => ({
  array1: [1,2,3,4,5]
}),
computed: {
  filtered() {
    return this.array1.map(item => `$${item}`);
  }
}
```

*Composition API*

```js
setup() {
  const array1 = reactive([1,2,3,4,5]);
  const filtered = computed(() => array1.map(item => `$${item}`));
  return {
    filtered
  }
}
```

Comment: so why still use computed？can i just do it this way:   
```
 const filtered =array1.value.map(item => '$'+ item) 
```

Comment: You could do that, it just wouldn't be reactive.  If `array1` changed later, `filtered` would not, but a computed would recalculate.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set it as a global filter and make it available to all your app components, do the following:

### main.js

```
const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  valueFilter(value) {
    return '$' + value
  }
}
```

### MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="(index,value) in array1" :key="index">
   {{ $filters.valueFilter(value) }}
  </li>
</ul>
</template>
```